# Find Nearest Location using Oracle Views only

Tags: sql, oracle, location, latitude-longitude

I have a use case where I need to find the nearest Employee using my current Latitude and Longitude. The integration I am using will only allow me to select from an Oracle table or view. I cannot use procedures.

**Employee Table Columns**

```
EmpID, Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Latitude, Longitude
```

The variables LAT and LNG will give me my current location.

An idea I had is to use something similar to the following:

```
SELECT Name,
       Address
FROM Employee
WHERE EmpID IN
    (SELECT EmpID
     FROM Employee
     WHERE Latitude BETWEEN LAT - .25 AND LAT + .25
       AND Longitude BETWEEN LNG - .25 AND LNG + .25)
```

The issue is that it will currently only display values +/- .25 and I would also like to have the results sort to show the nearest employee first.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

select * from where power(LAT - Latitude,2 )+power(LAT -Longitude,2) = (select min(power(LAT - Latitude,2 )+power(LAT -Longitude,2)) from Employee)

Is it OK?

Comment: select * from Employee order by power(LAT - Latitude,2 )+power(LAT -Longitude,2) asc;

Answer (score 0):

Do you use spatial in your Oracle, then  you've spatial queries:

`SDO_NN` uses the spatial index to identify the nearest neighbors for a geometry.

For eg:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM   your_table r
   WHERE  SDO_NN(r.geometry_column, querying_geometry,  
                 'sdo_num_res=1 distance=50 unit=meter') = 'TRUE';
```

Read more in [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm#i78067)

Comment: I am not sure how to pass lat/long into this one?

Answer (score 0):

Without Oracle Spatial you have to use Pythagoras:

```
select Name, Address, Latitude, Longitude,
   SQRT(POWER(Latitude-Lat, 2) + POWER(Longitude-Lng, 2)) as distance
from Employee
order by distance
```

I know, since you have Lat/Lon instead of cartesian coordinates the math. result is not 100% precise but it should fullfil your requirements.

Edit:
In oder to get only the closest employee you can use this one:

```
with t as 
   (select Name, Address, Latitude, Longitude,
      SQRT(POWER(Latitude-Lat, 2) + POWER(Longitude-Lng, 2)) as distance,
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Address ORDER BY SQRT(POWER(Latitude-Lat, 2) + POWER(Longitude-Lng, 2))) as dist_rank
   from Employee)
select *
from t
where dist_rank = 1
```

Comment: Anyway to move the derived column: SQRT(POWER(Latitude-Lat, 2) + POWER(Longitude-Lng, 2)) to the where clause some how? I need to select directly from a table or view and can't have a derived column.